# Generate TextViews with loop and enable click for each one

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

i'm making an Android App and in my activity that follows i execute a query to the database and i take the results. I take the results and make TextViews to the Activity. I want when i click the TextView, to pass to the next Activity the name of the Restaurant i click. The problem with my code is that for all the TextViews it save the name of the last Restaurant. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
public class ViewRestaurants extends Activity{
String name;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.row_restaurant);

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
db.open();

Cursor c = db.getSpRestaurants(getIntent().getStringExtra("city"), getIntent().getStringExtra("area"), getIntent().getStringExtra("cuisine"));

View layout =  findViewById(R.id.items);

if(c.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        name = c.getString(0);
        TextView resname = new TextView(this);
        TextView res = new TextView(this);
        View line = new View(this);

        resname.setText(c.getString(0));
        resname.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        resname.setTextSize(30);
        resname.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);

        res.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        res.setText(c.getString(1)+","+c.getString(2)+","+c.getString(3)+"\n"+c.getString(4));
        res.setTextSize(20);
        res.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        res.setClickable(true);
        res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide", "com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide.RestaurantDetails");
                i.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,2));
        line.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(resname);
        ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(res);
        ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(line);
    }while (c.moveToNext());

}

    db.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to make your `name` final within your loop and remove it as a class field in order to use it in the `OnClickListener` the way you are.

```
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        final String name = c.getString(0);

        //other code ...

        res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide", "com.mdl.cyrestaurants.guide.RestaurantDetails");
                i.putExtra("name",name);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //more code...

    }while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes

```
String name = c.getString(0);
resname.setText(name);
```

The reason why it is setting to the last restaurant name is because string is being passed by reference rather than by value as it is an object. Creating a unique string within the scope of the do while loop should solve this.

Comment: If i do this then the onClick() function doesn't recognize the "name"